# Looping folder deleting Powershell script until input is "Enter"

Tags: powershell

i have this script, that helpes me to delete folder upon name inputs on the prompt and then loops the script so i be able to delete one folder after the next. the loop and everything works fine so far. but it keeps looping and looping. i would like the script to end when i just press ENTER instead of writing a name on the prompt, and end without error's.
i am an absolut beginner and old, please explain slowly  / just starting with powershell and try to make some scripts that make work easier for me. be friendly please. thank you

this is the script for deleting folders (ending with errors)

```
do {

$destination = 'E:\TestEnv\deleted_images\'
$ListFile = 'E:\TestEnv\deleted_images\' 
get-childitem $ListFile
$Foldername = Read-host -prompt "Please Enter Folder name to be deleted"
$FilePath = Join-Path $ListFile $FileName
$FileExists =  test-path $FilePath 

If ($FileExists -eq $True) 
{
Remove-item $Foldername
Write-Host "Folder was deleted "
}
} while($Foldername -match'.+')
```

i use this script to move folders and it works like a charm. when i have moved all the desired folders, i just hit enter end the script ends and the powershell windows is closed.

this is the script for moving folders (working fine)

```
do {

$destination = 'E:\TestEnv\deleted_images'
$ListFile = 'E:\TestEnv\Repository\images\' 
get-childitem $ListFile
$Filename = Read-host -prompt "Please Enter File to be moved"
$FilePath = Join-Path $ListFile $FileName
$FileExists =  test-path $FilePath 

If ($FileExists -eq $True) {
move-item $FilePath $destination
Write-Host "File is moved to $destination "
}
} while($Filename -match'.+')
```

Comment: Your loop exit condition should be `until(-not $Foldername)`

Comment: hola santiago,  i still get a error message, because he can't handle the ENTER input.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: To complement @SantiagoSquarzon answer and taken the fact that you do quiet somethings in the loop. You might consider another programming approach: loop forever (`while($True)`) and (immediately)  exit the loop when you press enter (`if (-not $Filename) { break }`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hash table to validate the user input, its safer this way and you can also pass in the instance to `Remove-Item` through the pipeline in case of a valid input.

You should also be aware that `Join-Path` will give you a valid path in case no input is given on this line:

```
$FilePath = Join-Path $ListFile $FileName
```

For instance, `Join-Path 'C:\temp' -ChildPath ''` will output `C:\temp\`, hence the condition `If ($FileExists -eq $True) {` seems to be met every time

```bash
do {
    $files = Get-ChildItem 'E:\TestEnv\Repository\images\' -File |
        Group-Object Name -AsHashTable

    $files.Values
    $userinput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter File name to be deleted'

    if ($files.ContainsKey($userinput)) {
        $files[$userinput] | Remove-Item
        Write-Host 'Folder was deleted'
    }
}
until([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($userinput))
```

Comment: i used your code and it kind of works. means the error's are not coming but the folders which i input are not deleted. i changed the path on the $files string to the right one though but still not working means not deleting the folders i input

Comment: @sanjacob if you want to delete folders remove `-File` on the line `$files = Get-ChildItem 'E:\TestEnv\Repository\images\' -File` . To delete folders add  `-Recurse` to `Remove-item` . This should delete your specified folder and any files and subfolders within it.

Answer (score 0):

ok, as said i am absolutely new to powershell and to be honest i did not get all you tried to explain me, but with the code postet and the one i had, i could come to a version that works as i wanted. so thank you and every one else very much for your help.

the working version looks like this:

```
do 
{
$files = Get-ChildItem 'E:\TestEnv\deleted_images\' |
        Group-Object Name -AsHashTable

    $files.Values
    $userinput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter Folder name to be deleted'

    if ($files.ContainsKey($userinput)) {
        $files[$userinput] | Remove-item
        Write-Host 'Folder was deleted'
    }
    }
    until([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($userinput))
```

best regards
sanjacob